# Check if function executed successfully jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write unit test cases using jasmine. I have a scenario where I am passing data to function with different properties I just want to check if that function is getting executed successfully or with out any error. I tried `expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalled()` but it expects a spy instead of a function. Please suggest any way to write a test case expectation in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toHaveBeenCalled()` can be used only with the `spy`.

Create a `spy` on your method and try this

```
spyOn(obj, 'foo');
obj.foo();  // call foo()
expect(obj.foo).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: What is `obj` wrt original question? Also, the test makes little sense. `obj.foo` obviously has been called the line above the assertion :)

Comment: Forgive me. This is very much w.r.t angular as opposed to angularjs. I thought it to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to test, exactly?

1. Test that `foo` is working correctly. In that case, just call `foo()` from your test. If it throws, the test will fail.
2. Test that some *other* function `bar` is working correctly, where "correctly" means that it should call `foo`. In that case, create a spy for `foo` and use `toHaveBeenCalled()` on the spy. This may require that you restructure your code so you can somehow inject the `foo` spy into `bar`.

From your description, it seems that you want both at the same time, which goes against the principle of *unit* testing: you test one thing at a time.